# Is it possible to append multiple Crystal Reports in a single viewer?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm trying to generate several reports and show them as one document in a viewer.

Can't seem to find any way of doing this.

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 Suggestions:

1) To give the appearance of one viewer with multiple reports you could append viewers to the page and suppress all toolbars.

2) To have multiple reports for a single viewer you would need to make each of the reports a subreport in another report.

3) If the report is not going to be interactive(ie - paging, links, drill down, etc) you could just generate pdf's for each report and merge them.

Comment: What do you mean by `you could append viewers to the page and suppress all toolbars.` anyone can give me the steps for this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is the identity of the reports known at design time?  If so, you could embed all of them into another report as sub reports and run the parent report

Comment: The format is known, but the data is produced programmatically. Thanks!

Comment: So are you having trouble with combining reports or with running them with programmatically-created data (as opposed to data from a database)?  Or both?

Comment: I can run a report and display it in the viewer with no problems. I'm not sure how I can combine several reports and show them all in a single viewer, as one document.

Comment: Your best bet, as far as I know, would be to make them all sub-reports of a parent report.